# sum() operation on a data frame using variable reference

Tags: r, variables, reference

I have 2 data frames.

1. `msf` has 2 rows and few hundred columns, each column head being a stock name and consisting all numerical elements.
2. `currList` has many rows each of which has a stock name.

`msf`:-

```
  s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 
 1 0  1  0  0  1  0  
 2 0  0  1  0  1  0
```

`currList`:-

```
 1 s2
 2 s4
 3 s5
 4 s7
```

I want to find the column sum of `msf` for each stock in `currList`. I tried this:

```
for curr in 1:nrow(currList){ 
    currSum<- sum(paste("msf$",curr, sep=""))
    ....    
    }
```

It gave an error as:

```
Error in sum(paste("msf$", curr, sep = "")) : 
  invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

I am new to programming and R and need help to achieve what I want.

Comment: Step 1, unstack msf (`msf = msf.unstack()`). The result can be joined with `currList` almost directly (you need to add some column names). The unstacked view is how I would normally manipulate this data, with the stacked view saved for viewing or charting it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is bit unclear but assuming my understanding is correct,
it can be solved as followings :

```
data = data.frame(t(sample(50, 10)))
data
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
 1 36  8 24 47  3 33 44  7 45  21

currlist = data.frame(c("X1", "X5", "X6"))
colnames(currlist) = "stocks"
currlist
   stocks
1     X1
2     X5
3     X6 

rowSums(data[ ,colnames(data) %in% currlist$stocks])
```

However all of above is not standard / effective way of storing
and processing data. You can go over basic data structure and manipultation techniques for the better understanding.

Comment: I think you can just use `rowSums(data[ ,currlist$stocks])` assuming all stocks are in the data frame.